# Is there an R function to do a pairwise Levenshtein distance calculation of two vectors of strings?

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance

I have two vectors of strings:

```
a <- c('Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta')
b <- c('Epsilon', 'Zeta', 'Eta', 'Theta')
```

and I would like to compute the Levenshtein distance or edit distance for each pair of strings.

If I use

```
stringdist(a, b, method="lv")
```

The output is a vector with the Levenshtein distance of each string in vector a and the corresponding string in vector b (i.e., Alpha vs Epsilon, Beta vs Zeta, etc.).

What I need instead is a pairwise comparison between each string in one vector and ALL the other strings in the other vector (i.e. Alpha vs Epsilon, Alpha vs. Zeta, Alpha vs Eta, Alpha vs. Theta, Beta vs Epsilon, etc.).

Thanks

Comment: This probably doesn’t exist: having a dedicated function to perform a given function on all pairwise combinations, for each function, would add insane complexity. Instead, you decompose the problem and solve the individual problems separately: (1) create all pairwise combinations (e.g. using `expand_grid`), (2) perform your operation (here: `stringdist`) on all pairwise combinations generated in step 1.

Comment: Yes this is a great solution, thank you. I'm very new to coding, so I had no idea how to create the vector of combinations. Bit expand_grid is the way to go. Thank you

Comment: @KonradRudolph the `stringdist` package does contain a `stringdistmatrix` function which exists to do pairwise comparisons on two vectors, with the option of preserving row and column names. This can easily be pivoted.

Answer (score 6):

There is a straightforward way to do this using `stringdistmatrix` and some reshaping:

```r
library(stringdist)
library(tidyverse)

a <- c('Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta')
b <- c('Epsilon', 'Zeta', 'Eta', 'Theta')

stringdistmatrix(a, b, method = "lv", useNames = "string") %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "a") %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "b", values_to = "dist")
#> # A tibble: 16 x 3
#>    a     b        dist
#>    <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 Alpha Epsilon     7
#>  2 Alpha Zeta        4
#>  3 Alpha Eta         4
#>  4 Alpha Theta       4
#>  5 Beta  Epsilon     7
#>  6 Beta  Zeta        1
#>  7 Beta  Eta         2
#>  8 Beta  Theta       2
#>  9 Gamma Epsilon     7
#> 10 Gamma Zeta        4
#> 11 Gamma Eta         4
#> 12 Gamma Theta       4
#> 13 Delta Epsilon     6
#> 14 Delta Zeta        2
#> 15 Delta Eta         3
#> 16 Delta Theta       3
```

Answer (score 4):

A base R option using `adist` + `expand.grid`

```
> cbind(expand.grid(a = a, b = b), lv = c(adist(a, b)))
       a       b lv
1  Alpha Epsilon  7
2   Beta Epsilon  7
3  Gamma Epsilon  7
4  Delta Epsilon  6
5  Alpha    Zeta  4
6   Beta    Zeta  1
7  Gamma    Zeta  4
8  Delta    Zeta  2
9  Alpha     Eta  4
10  Beta     Eta  2
11 Gamma     Eta  4
12 Delta     Eta  3
13 Alpha   Theta  4
14  Beta   Theta  2
15 Gamma   Theta  4
16 Delta   Theta  3
```

or

```
> cbind(rev(expand.grid(b = b, a = a)), lv = c(t(adist(a, b))))
       a       b lv
1  Alpha Epsilon  7
2  Alpha    Zeta  4
3  Alpha     Eta  4
4  Alpha   Theta  4
5   Beta Epsilon  7
6   Beta    Zeta  1
7   Beta     Eta  2
8   Beta   Theta  2
9  Gamma Epsilon  7
10 Gamma    Zeta  4
11 Gamma     Eta  4
12 Gamma   Theta  4
13 Delta Epsilon  6
14 Delta    Zeta  2
15 Delta     Eta  3
16 Delta   Theta  3
```

Comment: Very nice! Another Thomas classic +1

Comment: I must say I’m quite impressed by the simplicity of this solution. Well done!